# Itext 7 Error at file pointer

Tags: itext7

I read the a.pdf in Itext 5 and it is good. But the same pdf is read in Itext 7. I have next error, when I use PdfSigner: 
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 7,907.

Comment: Show us your code and share your PDF file.

Comment: In particular without the file there is nothing we can do but guess wildly.

Comment: This is the .pdf:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VDtyEgDRwPlNbzECa9BRT78ajPtrfL9s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code is the example from Itext7    http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/signatures/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter03/C3_01_SignWithCAcert.java